# How to deploy Flutter Web Site on AWS EC2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, flutter, amazon-ec2, webdeploy, flutter-web

Good day to all!

I am developing a web application on the Flutter framework and have reached the deployment stage.
I deployed a project on AWS using the guide “https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=htuHNO9JeRU&feature=youtu.be”.
Then, I had to change the public ip address to my domain and then the problems started. I read a lot of guides and AWS documentation on setting a domain name, but it was unsuccessful.
Who is developing on Flutter Web, please help me deal with the problem of connecting my domain, or maybe there is another way to deploy Flutter Web on AWS?

I would be grateful for your help!